# RxJava collect AMPQ event in an Observable and subscribe with a buffer

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have to collect some AMPQ events and then print them every 10 sec using a buffer.

```
private Observable<Event> obs = Observable.empty(); 
private final Disposable disposable = obs.buffer(10, SECONDS)
                              .retry(t -> true)
                              .subscribe(System.out::println);

@Override
public void handle(final Event event, final MessageContext context) throws MessageConsumptionException {
      obs = obs.concatWith(Observable.just(event));
}
```

*Event* is the message and *void handle* is the consumer.

I debug this code and it print only an empty list, and it makes sense because *obs* is empty.

How can I add (concat?) events into this Observable and execute the *disposable* continually?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) which you can subscribe to.
New elements can be pushed into a Subject using `next(T element)`

```
private Subject<Event> subject = ReplaySubject.create();

@Override
public void handle(final Event event, final MessageContext context) throws MessageConsumptionException {
     subject.next(event);
}

public Observable<Event> getObservable() {
    return subject.asObservable();
}
```

You can subscribe to the observable, that is returned by the `getObservable()` method.